# Don't print the output of system call

Tags: c++, linux, wget, system-calls

I am trying to do a wget with timeout, and the program keep displaying all system calls for checking if wget is still running(for this I am using pgrep), is there any way to not display the result of pgrep call?

```
std::string systemCall{};
    systemCall = "wget " + downloadLink + " &";
    system(systemCall.c_str());

    time_t timer_old, timer_current;
    time(&timer_old);

    int activeWget = 0;
    do
    {
            activeWget = system("pgrep wget"); //always print the process id of wget
     } while ((activeWget == 0) && (difftime(timer_current, timer_old) < 3));
```

Comment: 1) *Never* use `system()`. It's a security nightmare. 2) If you just want the process ID then there are many better ways - like; obtain it when you spawn a process, read `/proc/`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to continue using `system()`, then just pipe the output to /dev/null:

```
    system("mycall 2>&1 >/dev/null");
```

A better way to achieve this, would be to use something like this:

```cpp
    string exec(const string& cmd, int32_t& returnCode) {
        char outputBuffer[512];
        string commandOutput;

        FILE* pipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

        if (!pipe)
            // you'd have to throw a system_error or something here; or just remove the exception
            throw getSysError(errno, "Failed to start process!");

        try {
            while (!feof(pipe) && fgets(outputBuffer, sizeof(outputBuffer) / sizeof(outputBuffer[0]), pipe) != NULL) {
                commandOutput += outputBuffer;
            }
        } catch (...) {
            returnCode = pclose(pipe);
            throw;
        }

        returnCode = pclose(pipe);
        return commandOutput;
    }

    void foo() {
        int32_t returnCode = 0;
        const string exe = "mycmd -poption";

        exec(exe, returnCode); // and just ignore the return value
    }
```

I'll note the above is somewhat legacy code, but I've used it successfully for a while